# Scala.js - Graphs

Tags: javascript

I've got Restful services wired using `scala.js` , and trying to create graphs for the application. Are there any good graph visualization libraries that integrate well with `scala.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried out the D3.js library , has an api for scala.js : https://goo.gl/9EX2GC

Other helpful Sample Code on git: https://goo.gl/0xht0P